# sqlsrv_query wait until execution is done

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have a working sqlsrv_query in my PHP code, but when I query a stored procedure in the SQL database which contains calculations, my sqlsrv_query cannot return its result. I always have an empty set of array to be fetched everytime I execute that certain stored procedure in the database. All queries that won't take so much time and calculations are working good.

```
$qry = "exec _ViewReceiveMessagesSample";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($link, $qry);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
{
    //stuffs
}
```

Please help.